# -Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO for glassfish?

Tags: jsf, glassfish

Do we have anything like -Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO for glassfish also?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Glassfish uses a different EL implementation which behaves by default already the same as when you would set `-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO` to `false` on Tomcat and clones.

Perhaps you're looking for the following JSF context parameter.

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Note that the above is even required on Tomcat and clones and well if your intent is to let JSF set empty string submitted values as `null` instead of `0`  on primitive wrapper properties like `Long`, `Integer`, etc.

Comment: thanks BalusC. This what I was looking for. I need to try it still. But i have one doubt that is this property only limited to Strings or it will take care of not converting integers, double,decimal etc to null also?

Comment: This setting lets JSF interpret empty HTTP request parameter value as `null`. The `COERCE_TO_ZERO=false` setting lets Tomcat interpret empty EL expression results for primitive wrappers like `Long`, `Integer`, etc as `null` instead of primitive's default. It are two different things.